# Precedence in regular expressions

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, regular-expressions

I'm having trouble finding the language represented by the following:

(AA|BB)*

Should the expression be read as... ( A (A|B) B ) *
or... ( (AA) | (BB) )*

If that isn't clear, should this produce something like... ABABAB or should it produce AABBAABBBBAA

My guess is that AABBAA is part of the represented language, while AB is not.

Comment: You are correct. The notational convention is that concatenation binds tighter than alternation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Regular expression $(AA|BB)*$ can accept any string having two consecutive A's or B's i.e. even number of consecutive A's and even number of consecutive B's. so `AABBAA` is in it but `AB` is not in it.

Comment: No! AAA and ABBA have at least two consecutive A's or B's but neither matches the regular expression.

Comment: Hi David, I missed this point, I will make edit to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This depends entirely on convention; with respect to a (proper) formal definition, the expression is invalid as it not properly parenthesised. I'd say that typically, the order is (from stronger to weaker binding)

- Kleene Star/Plus (also finite versions),
- concatenation,
- alternative.

Note that this corresponds (visually) to exponentiation over multiplication over addition in basic arithmetics, so it's probably the natural way.

That is,

- $10^*1$ is read as $1(0)^*1$ and
- $10|01|11$ as $(10)|(01)|(11)$.

Note that I still drop parentheses due to associativity of concatenation and alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is :

```
  (AA+BB)* =AABBAABBBBAA
```

if it has to be like starting with A and ending with B concept then probably
they would have provided the parenthesis like:

```
   (A(A+B)B)*  =ABABABABB
```